# Translate dynamic content loaded with ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-translate

I'm looking everywhere to find out how to translate dynamic content loaded with js ajax (or innerHTML).

I expect that h2 paragraph is translated but not happens.
Am I mistaken?
Thanks.
I write here because I can't find any doc.

[Link to JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fedrun/kj735q8L)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>language test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bower-angular-translate/2.0.1/angular-translate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bower-angular-translate-loader-url/2.0.0/angular-translate-loader-url.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('languageTest', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
            .config(function($translateProvider) {
                $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
                $translateProvider.translations('en', {
                    TITLE: 'Hello',
                    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
                    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
                    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
                });
                $translateProvider.translations('de', {
                    TITLE: 'Hallo',
                    FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
                    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
                    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
                });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="languageTest">
<h1><span>{{'FOO'|translate}}</span></h1>

<h2 id="h2load"></h2>

<button onclick="loadh2()">load h2</button>
<script>
    function loadh2(){
        document.getElementById("h2load").innerText = "{{'TITLE'|translate}}";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vq58tga9/

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but my problem is translate something that is loaded with an ajax..

Comment: updated [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fedrun/7k9r4qs3/1/)

Comment: the problem is if you use plain javascript not inside a controller it's not interpreted by angularjs and therefore no translation happens. you need to modify the element from within angular and then compile the element:
https://jsfiddle.net/ko6a5ncL/

Comment: SOLVED: Thank's a lot John